# Configure Routes In Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I already try this, but not success.

```
URL IS: domain.com/grand/parent/child
```

In routes

```
$route['grand/(:any)'] = "smm/index/$1";
```

In Controller

```
public function index($parent = NULL){
    // This is parent option//
    Echo '$parent';

    // This is child Section
    Echo '$child';
}
```

My Question is: How can i echo $child ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$route['grand/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'grand/index/$1/$2';
```

and

```
public function index($parent,$child){
echo $child;
}
```

should work.